# isotopy doesn't make sense (Milnor)

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

hello,

I am having a hard time following this isotopy put forth by Milnor in On the Total Curvature of Knots

> For each $c$ and $p$ in
>   $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ such that $\|c-p\|
> > < r$, there is an isotopy, $f_u^{c\;
> > p} (\gamma), 0 \le u \le 1$, of
>   $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ onto itself which
>   transforms $c$ into $p$ and leaves
>   fixed all points of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$
>   outside the $(n-2)$-sphere of radius $r$

This concept makes sense, but the paper continues saying:

For example,

$f_u^{c\; p}(\gamma) = \gamma - u ( 1 - \frac{\|\gamma - c\|}{r} )(p -c)$ for $\|\gamma - c\| \le r$

$f_u^{c\; p}(\gamma) = \gamma$ for $\|\gamma - c\| \ge r$

If you plug the value $\gamma = c$ into this where $u = 1$, you get

$c - (1)(1)(p-c) = 2c - p$

I thought the idea was to transform c into p?

It seems weird that you have the vector $p-c$ with some appropriate magnitude being subtracted instead of added.

Any thoughts on this would be really helpful,

Thanks

Comment: I suspect there is simply a typo, and that the defintion of $f^{c p}_u(\gamma)$ should be $\gamma + u(\text{etc. ...})$.

Comment: I hope you're right

Comment: Dear Ori, If you change the $-$ to a $+$ instead, doesn't everything then make sense?  If so, then I'm right!

Comment: Emerton, you're right. In order to understand this isotopy, I strongly suggest drawing a picture of the function $\varphi(\gamma) = ( 1 - \frac{\|\gamma - c\|}{r} )$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I'm entering my comment above as an answer here, so as to stop this question being bumped to the front page in the future.]

There is simply a typo: the definition of $f_u^{cp}(\gamma)$ should be
$\gamma + u$(etc. ...).